# Unable to obtain TCP/HTTP traffic from WPA2 packets even with full handshake and decryption

Tags: wpa2, wireshark, decryption, sniffing

## The Problem

On my WPA2 network, I have been successfully able to get intercept a full four-message EAPOL handshake from a particular computer on my network. It is my understanding that with this handshake (and knowing the passphrase for my network), I should be able to decrypt not only broadcast traffic, but also internet traffic from that computer whose handshake I captured, since its communication with the access point is encrypted using data exchanged in the handshake and the PMK (computed from the SSID and passphrase data).

However, I still seem to only be decrypting "broadcast" traffic. There is no TCP traffic from the computer whose handshake I captured even though I visited unencrypted HTTP sites on it and used netcat on it to communicate with another computer on the WLAN. I can tell that at least the broadcast data is correctly decrypted because I can look at the encrypted and decrypted hex codes for those packets (they happen to primarily be MDNS, ICMP, ARP, etc.). I even tried to take the data and decrypt it with airdecap-ng but this did not work either.

It seems that based on examples of packet data I've been able to play with in Wireshark that I should be able to get this traffic. In particular, [this guide](https://mrncciew.com/2014/08/16/decrypt-wpa2-psk-using-wireshark/) shows how to do it and provides a pcap file on which you can easily decrypt the WPA2 packets and get a bunch of TCP packets in Wireshark. Similarly, the [Wireshark Wiki explains](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) how to do this in addition to providing pcap samples that also can be decrypted to yield TCP traffic.

### My Setup

- Kali Linux Live Persistence on USB
- Alfa AWUS036H in monitor mode (using airmon-ng)
- WLAN with WPA2, no WPS
- Wireshark IEEE 802.11 Preferences:

  - Enable decryption IS checked
  - Ignore the Protection bit is set to No
  - Decryption keys include a wpa2-pwd entry in the format of passphrase:ssid

### Main Question

Why am I not able to pick up the TCP traffic from the computer for which I intercepted a full EAPOL handshake from, the way that I was able to do so in the sample pcap files I have linked? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how this works, or is this likely the result of a hardware or network related issue?

Comment: My guess is that your NIC isn't actually in monitor mode.

Comment: I used airmon-ng which added interface wlan0mon in lieu of wlan0, and I confirmed on iwconfig that it was in monitor mode. I also ensured that monitor mode was enabled on wlan0mon in Wireshark before capturing, and used that interface. Also, it had to see a handshake before decrypting broadcast messages which is only necessary on monitor mode since the nic is not actually connected to the network and the computer doesn't get a handshake of its own.

Comment: Then I don't know. I guess you've checked if you're receiving the encrypted frames at the very least

Comment: I'm receiving some encrypted frames that wireshark decrypts but they don't seem to include the primary Internet traffic, just mainly broadcast/ARP messages.

Comment: That's a hint that your interface is not actually in full monitor mode: you get the broadcast frames, not unicasts or multicasts not meant to you. That being said, I don't have any solution to offer, I'm afraid. The problem could come from your adapter, drivers or setup.

Comment: But I am getting some multicast and unicast messages. For example, I captured/decrypted multicast ICMP and MDNS packets from the target computer whose handshake I captured (they were addressed to ipv4 and ipv6 multicast addresses). I did just notice that I captured a bunch of "Request-to-send" frames between the target computer and AP (mixed in with "Clear-to-send" and "Block Ack" frames). There are also other 802.11 frames between devices on my LAN and the AP (RTS, CTS, BA, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was that my WLAN is setup as 802.11b/g/n, and the target devices I had been testing this on were all 802.11b/g/n compatible, so they were using 802.11n by default to directly communicate with the AP. As I realize now, the Alfa AWUS036H is only 802.11 b/g compatible, so it was was not able to intercept the 802.11n traffic! Once I switched my router to only use b/g, then I was able to capture the TCP traffic as expected.

**Lesson learned**: get a WiFi card that is actually compatible with modern wireless standards -_-